# How to align an address to a void pointer?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

In an application, I have a problem like this.
The method was designed to provide an generic interface for the user to get memory from a global memory pool, implemented like:

```
shmPool shm;
void getMemory(void* mPtr){
   mPtr = &shm;
}
```

but it is clear that the value of `mPtr` is not changed. How is it possible to align the value of a pointer to a unknown type pointer.

Comment: The `mPtr` pointer is passed by value, its value won't be changed outside of the function call. Also, isn't it a bit weird, having a `get` function that doesn't actually return anything ?

Comment: You seem to have two problems: (1) how to change `mPtr` and (2) how to align memory to a specified boundary. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: 1) You don't need to align the void pointer, it will get the alignment of the address of `shm`. 2) Your function does not return anything -- you should either pass in a pointer-to-pointer, or return a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply return the pointer, instead of using an out-parameter?

```
void* getMemory() {
    return &shm;
}
```

Comment: because I want the return value to represent whether the memory alloc is a success like 0 means success and 1 means system resource unavailable

Comment: In that case you could return a null-pointer to indicate failure. Or you could throw an exception.

Comment: I have consider the way of throwing an exception and I just want to learn another way, I am curious about that. I have solve it by using void** and reinterpret_cast, it worked well for me, still many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code, modified so the caller will receive the pointer to `shm`:

```
shmPool shm;
void getMemory(void** mPtr){
   *mPtr = &shm;
}
```

The caller will call this function like:

```
shmPool* p;
getMemory(&p);
// now p is a valid pointer
```

Your question has nothing to do with aligning memory. There are problems with your code though, so take my answer with a grain of salt:

1. Why are you casting the object to `void*`? This is almost certainly bad.
2. I agree with @Björn Pollex that in this example it's better to use a return value rather than an out parameter.

Comment: 1. I am doing a job like a memory management system, it pass the pointer to the method and then allocate share memory to the pointer.

Comment: 2.well it surely will work to return a void*, i am just curious if there is another way. void** and interpret_cast works well, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`mPtr` is a local variable. Only the local copy is changed- why would any other variable get changed? If you want to change a different pointer, you will have to take a reference or pointer to it.

Comment: I did it with void**, taking a reference is a little dangerous. thanks

Comment: @Cyber_Rush: A reference is much less dangerous than a pointer.

Comment: Could you please tell more? I don't quite understand the basic part of this. THX